# Hard wire into a recessed fluorescent can

Tags: fluorescent

Can I /or how can I hard wire a new ceiling hanging pendant into the existing fluorescent can in my dining room. I live in a building and have no access above. 
Upgrade Time

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the fixture?

Comment: Is the new pendent replacing the recessed can and being mounted at that location? Or are you hanging the pop pendent somewhere nearby and hoping that it will be able to be connected to the existing recessed can?